# Tabular* environment stretching table more than page width

Tags: tables

I am using trying to use the `tabular*` environment to stretch a table to the page width. However the table gets stretched more than the page width defined on the preamble ...

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,margin=\parindent,tableposition=top]{caption}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}


\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.50in}

\parskip = 0pt
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\parskip}{.0in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\newcommand{\figref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eqnref}[1]{equation (\ref{#1})}
\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}

\newenvironment{Question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}


    \FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[!htbp]

  \centering
  \caption{AAAA}
  \caption*{AAAA}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} cccccll}
    \hline
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Panel A:}                                                                                                     \\ \hline
   & $\delta_1$           & t-stat               &                      & $\delta_2$           & t-stat               &  & $R^2$ \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-8} 
1  & -0.06                & -0.40                &                      & 0.8                  & 16.0                 &  & 0.05  \\
2  & 0.04                 & 0.23                 &                      & 3.3                  & 54.3                 &  & 0.39  \\
3  & 0.03                 & 0.19                 &                      & 1.7                  & 41.0                 &  & 0.27  \\
4  & 0.17                 & 0.89                 &                      & 2.2                  & 36.0                 &  & 0.22  \\
5  & 0.12                 & 0.88                 &                      & 1.2                  & 28.0                 &  & 0.15  \\
6  & 0.02                 & 0.13                 &                      & -1.9                 & -32.7                &  & 0.19  \\
7  & 0.04                 & 0.40                 &                      & 0.2                  & 5.9                  &  & 0.01  \\
8  & 0.13                 & 0.61                 &                      & 1.9                  & 27.2                 &  & 0.14  \\
9  & -0.02                & -0.22                &                      & -0.5                 & -14.8                &  & 0.05  \\
10 & 0.14                 & 1.11                 &                      & 0.3                  & 6.8                  &  & 0.01  \\
11 & -0.21                & -1.14                &                      & 0.5                  & 8.7                  &  & 0.02  \\
12 & -0.22                & -2.16                &                      & 0.4                  & 12.5                 &  & 0.03  \\ \hline
   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &       \\
   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Panel B:}                                                                                                     \\ \hline
   & $\delta_1$           & t-stat               &                      & $\delta_2$           & t-stat               &  & $R^2$ \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-8} 
1  & -0.13                & -0.58                &                      & 3.83                 & 55.00                &  & 0.40  \\
2  & -0.02                & -0.17                &                      & 2.35                 & 49.92                &  & 0.35  \\
3  & -0.05                & -0.39                &                      & 1.66                 & 40.55                &  & 0.26  \\
4  & -0.09                & -1.19                &                      & 0.79                 & 33.25                &  & 0.19  \\
5  & 0.00                 & 0.13                 &                      & -0.44                & -37.38               &  & 0.23  \\ \hline
   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &       \\
   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  &       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Panel C:}                                                                                                     \\ \hline
   & $\delta_1$           & t-stat               &                      & $\delta_2$           & t-stat               &  & $R^2$ \\ \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-8} 
1  & 0.07                 & 0.76                 &                      & -0.91                & -32.58               &  & 0.19  \\
2  & 0.04                 & 0.61                 &                      & 0.05                 & 2.24                 &  & 0.00  \\
3  & -0.05                & -0.65                &                      & 0.38                 & 14.25                &  & 0.04  \\
4  & -0.01                & -0.16                &                      & 0.69                 & 25.03                &  & 0.12  \\
5  & -0.10                & -0.60                &                      & 2.00                 & 37.21                &  & 0.23  \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}

  \label{tab:Reg1}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: stretching is just fine for me. Your missing MWE makes it unreproducable.

Comment: Please could you complete your code so that it compiles? Start with `\documentclass{...`. If I complete your code in the obvious way, the tabular fits fine into the width of the text body - not one overfull box is mentioned in the log file.

Comment: It's fine with both A4 and US letter....

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. Just added the preamble...

Comment: Your tabular fits fine. This isn't surprising since your preamble increases the text width, so if the table fits in the standard case, it is bound to fit with your custom settings. By the way, you could minimise the code posted considerably e.g. remove the packages which aren't needed for the example. You are also missing `\begin{document}...\end{document}`.

Comment: I confirm what @cfr said and add that such a table should not be widened: it becomes completely unreadable.

Comment: Thanks for both answers. The table fits but streches more than the text margins ...

Comment: @volcompt No, it doesn't. Add `\usepackage{showframe}` and you'll see that it fits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` device, LaTeX sets the width of each intercolumn space to `2\tabcolsep+\fill`. The default value of `\tabcolsep`, at least in most document classes I'm familiar with, is `6pt`.

If the "natural" width of the `tabular*` environment, i.e., with `\fill=0pt` (note: `\fill` can not be negative), exceeds the width of the text block, three possible remedies should be considered:

- Eliminate the whitespace to the left of the first column and to the right of the final column (total savings: `2\tabcolsep`);
- Execute the instruction `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}`. That way, each intercolumn whitespace is equal to `\fill`; and
- Reduce the font size, e.g., by executing an instruction such as `\small` or `\footnotesize`.

The code below shows the results of using a `tabular*` with 14 instead of "just" 6 data columns to create an example of the table's width exceeding that of the text block. The first `tabular*` environment uses the default value of `\tabcolsep`, whereas the second uses `\tabcolsep=0pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \caption{\texttt{\textbackslash tabcolsep=6pt} (default)} \label{tab:default}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{14}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14  \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Historical } \\
    Lab1 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0& 1.0 & 1.0 \\
    Lab2 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0& 1.0 & 1.0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}

    \bigskip\bigskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % default: 6pt
    \caption{\texttt{\textbackslash tabcolsep=0pt}} \label{tab:alt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{14}{c} }
    \toprule
    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14  \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Historical } \\
    Lab1 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0& 1.0 & 1.0 \\
    Lab2 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0& 1.0 & 1.0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after the OP augmented his/her posting to show a "real" table: Not sure what your concern is about the tabular material not fitting in the width of the text block. I did notice, though, that the table is too tall to fit into the text block. However, that's because you've changed the lowel-level TeX macro `\baselineskip`. Instead of modifying `\baselineskip` directly, I would load the `setstretch` package and issue the command `\setstretch{1.3}`; that way, material in footnotes, tables, and arrays will *not* be stretched vertically.

Your table has two unneeded column and a lot of unnecessary statements, c.f., all those `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}` directives. With some clean-up, replacing all `\hline` directives with `\midrule`s and all `\cline` statements with `\cmdirule`s, and using the `dcolumn` package to align numeric data on the respective decimal markers, one gets:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,margin=\parindent,tableposition=top]{caption}

%\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}

%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}


\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.50in}


\parskip = 0pt
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\parskip}{.0in}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\newcommand{\figref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\secref}[1]{Section~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\eqnref}[1]{equation (\ref{#1})}
\newcommand{\chapref}[1]{Chapter~\ref{#1}}

\newenvironment{Question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\begin{document}

    \FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[!htbp]

  %%\centering
  \caption{AAAA}
  \caption*{AAAA}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{5}{d{2.2}}}
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A:}\\ 
\midrule
& \mc{$\delta_1$} & \mc{t-stat}  & \mc{$\delta_2$} & \mc{t-stat} &  \mc{$R^2$} \\ 
   \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-6} 
1  & -0.06 & -0.40 & 0.8   & 16.0  &  0.05  \\
2  & 0.04  & 0.23  & 3.3   & 54.3  &  0.39  \\
3  & 0.03  & 0.19  & 1.7   & 41.0  &  0.27  \\
4  & 0.17  & 0.89  & 2.2   & 36.0  &  0.22  \\
5  & 0.12  & 0.88  & 1.2   & 28.0  &  0.15  \\
6  & 0.02  & 0.13  & -1.9  & -32.7 &  0.19  \\
7  & 0.04  & 0.40  & 0.2   & 5.9   &  0.01  \\
8  & 0.13  & 0.61  & 1.9   & 27.2  &  0.14  \\
9  & -0.02 & -0.22 & -0.5  & -14.8 &  0.05  \\
10 & 0.14  & 1.11  & 0.3   & 6.8   &  0.01  \\
11 & -0.21 & -1.14 & 0.5   & 8.7   &  0.02  \\
12 & -0.22 & -2.16 & 0.4   & 12.5  &  0.03  \\ 
\midrule
\\ \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B:}\\ 
\midrule
& \mc{$\delta_1$} & \mc{t-stat}  & \mc{$\delta_2$} & \mc{t-stat} &  \mc{$R^2$} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-6} 
1  & -0.13 & -0.58 & 3.83  & 55.00 &  0.40  \\
2  & -0.02 & -0.17 & 2.35  & 49.92 &  0.35  \\
3  & -0.05 & -0.39 & 1.66  & 40.55 &  0.26  \\
4  & -0.09 & -1.19 & 0.79  & 33.25 &  0.19  \\
5  & 0.00  & 0.13  & -0.44 & -37.38 &  0.23  \\ 
\midrule
\\ \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel C:}\\ 
\midrule
& \mc{$\delta_1$} & \mc{t-stat}  & \mc{$\delta_2$} & \mc{t-stat} &  \mc{$R^2$} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-6} 
1  & 0.07  & 0.76  & -0.91 & -32.58 &  0.19  \\
2  & 0.04  & 0.61  & 0.05  & 2.24  &  0.00  \\
3  & -0.05 & -0.65 & 0.38  & 14.25 &  0.04  \\
4  & -0.01 & -0.16 & 0.69  & 25.03 &  0.12  \\
5  & -0.10 & -0.60 & 2.00  & 37.21 &  0.23  \\
\midrule
\end{tabular*}

  \label{tab:Reg1}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have added : \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} to the table but nothing changed ...

Comment: @volcompt - please post a more realistic example, one that illustrates the actual issues you're facing. With the tabular materiel you've posted so far, setting `\tabcolsep` to zero very much makes a difference.

Comment: Hi Mico, thanks. I have edited my post and included the full table. It does not matter whether I add \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} or not, the table width is still bigger than the margins I am using. Thanks

Comment: @volcompt - I've provided an addendum to show how I would typeset your "real" table, while still using a `tabular*` environment.

Answer (score 3):

Your table fits in the stated margins. This is what I get if I add `\usepackage{showframe}` and the missing `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`

[image]

As you clearly see, it fits in the box representing the text block margins.

---

Here is how I'd typeset it: enlarging the table will simply make it unreadable.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,margin=\parindent,tableposition=top]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{AAAA}\label{tab:Reg1}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  r
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=-1.2]
  S[table-format=-2.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel A:} \\
\midrule
& {$\delta_1$} & {t-stat} & {$\delta_2$} & {t-stat} & {$R^2$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-6}
 1 & -0.06 & -0.40 &  0.8 &  16.0 & 0.05  \\
 2 &  0.04 &  0.23 &  3.3 &  54.3 & 0.39  \\
 3 &  0.03 &  0.19 &  1.7 &  41.0 & 0.27  \\
 4 &  0.17 &  0.89 &  2.2 &  36.0 & 0.22  \\
 5 &  0.12 &  0.88 &  1.2 &  28.0 & 0.15  \\
 6 &  0.02 &  0.13 & -1.9 & -32.7 & 0.19  \\
 7 &  0.04 &  0.40 &  0.2 &   5.9 & 0.01  \\
 8 &  0.13 &  0.61 &  1.9 &  27.2 & 0.14  \\
 9 & -0.02 & -0.22 & -0.5 & -14.8 & 0.05  \\
10 &  0.14 &  1.11 &  0.3 &   6.8 & 0.01  \\
11 & -0.21 & -1.14 &  0.5 &   8.7 & 0.02  \\
12 & -0.22 & -2.16 &  0.4 &  12.5 & 0.03  \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel B:} \\
\midrule
& {$\delta_1$} & {t-stat} & {$\delta_2$} & {t-stat} & {$R^2$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-6}
 1 & -0.13 & -0.58 &  3.83 &  55.00 & 0.40  \\
 2 & -0.02 & -0.17 &  2.35 &  49.92 & 0.35  \\
 3 & -0.05 & -0.39 &  1.66 &  40.55 & 0.26  \\
 4 & -0.09 & -1.19 &  0.79 &  33.25 & 0.19  \\
 5 &  0.00 &  0.13 & -0.44 & -37.38 & 0.23  \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Panel C:} \\
\midrule
& {$\delta_1$} & {t-stat} & {$\delta_2$} & {t-stat} & {$R^2$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-6}
 1 &  0.07 &  0.76 & -0.91 & -32.58 & 0.19  \\
 2 &  0.04 &  0.61 &  0.05 &   2.24 & 0.00  \\
 3 & -0.05 & -0.65 &  0.38 &  14.25 & 0.04  \\
 4 & -0.01 & -0.16 &  0.69 &  25.03 & 0.12  \\
 5 & -0.10 & -0.60 &  2.00 &  37.21 & 0.23  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]